# Screen manager and its screens having access over the screen manager

Tags: c++

I've got this here screen manager system and while it works rather well, I do worry on how practical it all is.

The application creates a screen manager class then enters a message loop which calls the update, render and handle input methods of the screen manager.

The screen manager has a vector container of unique_ptr's. 
The main container type is a virtual screen class. It looks like this.

I should mention that `vgSreen` has a forward declaration of `screenManager`.

```
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<vgScreen>> gameScreens;
this->AddScreen(std::unique_ptr<MainMenu>(new MainMenu()));
```

When the screen manager adds a screen it loads the screens content and initializes it, then adds it to the stack. When it initializes a screen it passes a pointer of itself like this. From here on I'm skeptical about the performance of the program.

```
gameScreenToAdd.Initialize(*this);
```

The game screen stores the screen manager parameter as a pointer:

```
bool MainMenu::Initialize(ScreenManager* sManager)
{
    //manager is a ScreenManager* pointer
    this->manager = sManager;
}
```

Then when a screen wants to add or remove itself or another screen it can do the following:

```
manager->AddScreen(std::unique_ptr<Gameplay>(new Gameplay()));
```

I believe the erase function may result in errors because when a `unique_ptr` is added to the vector, the vector size increases, but erasing the vector doesn't then resize the container.

```
bool ScreenManager::RemoveScreen(int index)
{
    unsigned int a = GetCount();

    gameScreen[index]->Shutdown();

    gameScreen[index].release();

    gameScreen.erase(gameScreen.begin() + index);

    return true;
}
```

If there's a better alternate than using a vector of unique pointers, or if I'm leaking horrendously by passing screen manager to each screen, let me know. Or if you have any thoughts on this in general.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I just happened to code my own StateMachine a week ago, which is similar to your ScreenManager, so here are my thoughts on the subject.

A vector of state *can* work, but I think using a stack instead saves you the index management. Also, the stack would resize itself during both pop and push operations.

A state (or a screen in your case) manages its own lifetime. As a consequence, it can remove itself from the stack during an update operation, and must survive until the next loop is processed. Thus, I choosed `std::shared_ptr` to work out this problem.

```cpp
std::stack<std::shared_ptr<Screen>> _screens;
```

Since you're using C++11, the more you avoid manual dynamic allocations, the better. Using templates, you can use a safer way of creating your screen, and even provide parameters to them :

```cpp
template<typename Screen, typename... Args>
void push_screen (Args && ... args)
{
    if (!_screens.empty())
        _screens.top()->pause(); // Pause the current state

    _screens.emplace(std::make_shared<Screen>(std::forward<Args>(args)...));
    // Or, if you still use std::unique_ptr
    // _screens.emplace(new Screen { std::forward<Args>(args)... }); // C++11
    // _screens.emplace(std::make_unique<Screen>(std::forward<Args>(args)...)); // C++14
    _screens.top()->enter(); // Start the new state
}
```

This way, you can pass a reference of your ScreenManager and avoid using a bare pointer.

```cpp
push_screen<MainMenuScreen>(*this);
```

Comment: Thank you so much :D I'm pretty ecstatic to put this into motion. Bless you :) I've never used templates before so that's something new to explore.

Comment: I also was ecstatic when seeing the whole thing work like a charm :)
If you begin with templates, you'll soon come accross many problems, don't forget to properly document yourself about them, it's pretty powerful and really useful with everyday modern C++ code.

Comment: How does using `std::ref` improve over raw pointers/references? It is only used from the call location of `push_screen` to `make_shared` and in this short area a raw reference would have worked as well.

Comment: @Nobody You're right, `std::ref` is pointless here. Note to self: rest before posting code based on memories ...